# Dataframe filter on two columns as pair from lists or dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Having a DataFrame like below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'COUNTRY':['PL', 'FR','NO','SE', 'IT', 'PL'], 'REGION':[1,3,1,2,2,3], SUBREGION':[1,2,3,4,6,8]})
```

[image]

and two lists:

```
country_list = ['IT', 'PL', 'FR']
region_list = [1,1,3]
```

I would like to filter the DataFrame on both lists where each item of each list is a pair like a `{'PL':1}` ensuring that only that combination is selected. That is why a regular filter like:

```
df[(df['COUNTRY'].isin(country_list)) & (df['REGION'].isin(region_list))]
```

will present a result that is unsatisfactory:

[image]

How I go about it for the moment is a very Excel like solution where I create a temp column and merge two lists together to have one key for filtering as below:

```
df = df.astype({'REGION':'str'})
region_list = list(map(str,region_list))
merged_list = list(zip(country_list,region_list))
merged_list =[''.join(i) for i in merged_list]
df['TEMP COL'] = df['COUNTRY'] + df['REGION']
df[df['TEMP COL'].isin(merged_list)]
```

[image]

This works but I wanted to check with the community if there is a more elegant approach you are using? Let me just note that having an option to filter on one dictionary instead of two lists would be even superior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create helper `DataFrame` and for filter use default inner join by default both columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'COUNTRY': country_list, 'REGION': region_list}).merge(df)
print (df)
  COUNTRY  REGION  SUBREGION
0      PL       1          1
1      FR       3          2
```

Or use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) by `MultiIndex` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.set_index(['COUNTRY','REGION']).index.isin(zip(country_list, region_list))]
print (df)
  COUNTRY  REGION  SUBREGION
0      PL       1          1
1      FR       3          2
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually tried an approach with set_index but couldn't get it working and now I do know how should I apply it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach (almost the same as yours):

```
out = df[df[['COUNTRY', 'REGION']].apply(tuple, axis=1).isin(zip(country_list, region_list))]
```

Output:

```
  COUNTRY  REGION  SUBREGION
0      PL       1          1
1      FR       3          2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try it this way:

```py
idx = pd.Series(index=df.index, data=False)
for cl, rl in zip(country_list,region_list):
    idx |= ((df['COUNTRY'] == cl) & (df['REGION'] == rl))
df[idx]
```

Output:

```
  COUNTRY  REGION  SUBREGION
0      PL       1          1
1      FR       3          2
```

In this way you do not need to make a surrogate "Excel" like column.